# Angular watch array item in service

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

How could I watch change an array element in a service?

For example we have some `CartController` and `ProductListService`.

In `ProductListService` we fetch items:

```
/**
 * Fetch all the products in user cart
 *
 * @return void
 */
this.all = function() {
    $http
        .get('/api/cart/all.php')
        .success(function(resp) {
            _this.products = resp.products;
        });
};
```

And `getter`:

```
/**
 * Getter for all user products
 *
 * @return array
 */
this.getProducts = function() {
    return _this.products;
};
```

In our `controller`:

```
$scope.getProducts = function() {
    return ProductListService.getProducts();
};
```

And in view:

```
<div class="price">
    <span ng-click="removeOne(product)">—</span>
    <input type="text" ng-model="product.PRODUCT.QUANTITY">
    <span ng-click="addOne(product)">+</span>
</div>
```

So the result we are expection is a simple cart with +/- buttons and input to type quantity in.

When we click on these icons +/- we are triggering `addOne/removeOne` methods (they are doing this `ProductListService.quantity(id, quantity);`)

But when we change `<input>`'s value - nothing happens because I can not watch it change.

The most idea I have is to watch change the whole `products` in our `service`:

```
// Here we will update product quantity on user input
$scope.$watch(
    function() {
        return ProductListService.products;
    }, 
    function(products, old) {
        // products will be full products list (not single product)
        // Here a lot of loops to determine what product quantity was changed
    },
    true
);
```

The target is to watch `ProductListService.products`.quantity change. So how could I do it?

Thanks

Comment: What needs to change when product.PRODUCT.QUANTITY changes?

Comment: need to call `ProductListService.quantity(id, quantity)` width needle params

Answer (score 0):

This is how I suggest you do it:

```
//HTML
<div ng-controller="ProductController as prodCtrl">
    <div class="productList" ng-repeat="product in prodCtrl.products">
        <div class="price">
                <span ng-bind="product.Name"></span>
                <span ng-click="prodCtrl.removeOne(product)">—</span>
                <input type="text" ng-model="product.Quantity">
                <span ng-click="prodCtrl.addOne(product)">+</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

//CONTROLLER
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('app')
        .controller('ProductController', ProductController);

    ProductController.$inject = ['$scope', 'ProductListService'];

    function ProductController($scope, ProductListService) {
        /* jshint validthis:true */

        $scope.removeOne = function (product) {
           //do whatever - product.Quantity is bound to your text box, no need to watch
           ProductListService.quantity(product.Id, product.Quantity)
        };
        $scope.addOne = function (product) {
           //do whatever - product.Quantity is bound to your text box, no need to watch
           ProductListService.quantity(product.Id, product.Quantity)
        };

    activate();

    function activate() {
         $scope.products=ProductListService.getProducts();
    }
    }
})();
```

Comment: I have to sync `ProductListService` products with other 5 controllers. For example if products of some `CatalogyController` change - we will need to rerun `activate()` method (with $rootScope, I guess). And it is not very comfortable..

Comment: Create a <div ng-controller="MainController as main"> nest your other controllers within it. Then set products on the MainController and access the products in each sub controller via $scope.main.products.